# How can I check if the private key of Ethereum is valid in C#?

Tags: c#, ethereum

I searched about Wallet.fromPrrivateKey in ethereumjs-wallet, and privateKeyVerify in secp256k1. But I'm using Unity & Nethereum, so I can't use that. Is there any way to validate the private key in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The private key is just a random 256-bit integer number.

You just need to check it is `> 0` and `< max private key value` [that can be found here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/82946/620).

Private keys do not have checksums or anything like that.

Comment: Yesterday I wrote some code to check if the key is 256-bit alphanumeric because I thought it would be very difficult to check the key through the secp256k1 curve. And judging from your anwser, it was right. Thank you for answering,  Mikko Ohtamma!

Comment: Remember to press "Correct answer check" if the answer is correct :)